# Adding a custom activation function in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement a custom activation function in Keras
The function is following

```
def picewise(x):
   if x > 0.5 :
      return 1
   elif if x < 0.5:
      return 0
   else:
      return x + 0.5
```

I call the activation function as

```
model.add(Dense(128,activation = picewise))
```

But I am getting a whole bunch of errors. How can i successfully implement the above as a working activation function in Keras

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `x` is not a primitive type. `x` is a tensor. So the way you are trying to implement the activation function will not work. You probably need something like the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
def picewise(x):
    z = tf.where(x >= 0.5, x - x + 1.0 , x)
    y = tf.where(z <= -0.5,z -  z + 0, z + 0.5)
    return y
```